# apache ignite 2.10.0 heap starvation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, ignite

After upgrading from 2.7.1 version to 2.10.0 version ignite nodes facing huge full GC operations after 24-36 hours after node start.

We try to increase heap size but no luck, here is the start configuration for nodes;

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xms12g -Xmx12g -server -javaagent:/etc/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=8090:/etc/prometheus/jmx.yml -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49165 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g -DIGNITE_SKIP_CONFIGURATION_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=true -DIGNITE_WAL_MMAP=true -DIGNITE_BPLUS_TREE_LOCK_RETRIES=100000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xloggc:/var/log/apache-ignite/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M"
```

here is the 80 hours of GC analyize report: https://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMjEvMDgvMzEvLS1nYy5sb2cuMC5jdXJyZW50LnppcC0tNS01MS0yOQ==&channel=WEB

do we need more heap size or is there a BUG that we need to be aware?

here is the node configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="gridLogger">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/etc/apache-ignite/ignite-log4j2.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="communicationSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
            <property name="usePairedConnections" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
    <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="128"/>
    <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="128"/>
    <property name="queryThreadPoolSize" value="128"/>
    <property name="serviceThreadPoolSize" value="128"/>
    <property name="stripedPoolSize" value="128"/>
    <property name="dataStreamerThreadPoolSize" value="4"/>
    <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="16"/>

    <!-- Explicitly enable peer class loading. -->
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

    <!-- Enable deploymentSpi, /usr/share/apache-ignite/libs/segmentify directory will be checked every 5 seconds for changed files-->
    <property name="deploymentSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.UriDeploymentSpi">
            <property name="temporaryDirectoryPath" value="/tmp/temp_ignite_libs"/>
            <property name="uriList">
                <list>
                    <value>file://freq=5000@localhost/usr/share/apache-ignite/libs/segmentify/</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="default"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="networkTimeout" value="60000"/>
    <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- THERE ARE 10 NODES -->
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite native persistence. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{ 2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{ 40L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="storagePath" value="/srv/ignite/persist"/>
            <property name="walPath" value="/srv/ignite/wal"/>
            <property name="walArchivePath" value="/srv/ignite/wal"/>
            <property name="walMode" value="LOG_ONLY"/>
            <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{ 256L * 1024 * 1024 }"/>
            <property name="walFlushFrequency" value="5000"/>
            <property name="maxWalArchiveSize" value="#{ 512L * 1024 * 1024 }"/>
            <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="checkpointFrequency" value="300000"/>
            <property name="checkpointWriteOrder" value="SEQUENTIAL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Get a session expired when I click the link.

Answer (score 0):

(A comment that grew too large)
Looking at the log @reclaimed bytes, the reclaimed size steadily declines until you seem to reclaim almost no memory at all, with a steadily increasing number of full gc:s (there is no heap left to allocate) so the JVM tries again and again with a full gc until finally the full gc frees up something like 10 GB. 
Looking at Old Gen graph, it looks a bit like you have a memory leak but suddenly everything clears up. You see that reclamation gives less and less until it doesn't give anything and the number of gc:s increase.

It's hard to say something about this, really, without knowing more. 
Some things to think about:

- behaviour pattern
  (Given the current setup, is this recurring?)Ok, this is recurring.
- Client behaviour
  Are the clients connecting to the system behaving in some other way than before?
- Configuration
  When you upgraded, was there any configuration changes? default behaviours that changed and so on?
- Have something changed in the work that you submit?

Increasing the heap space will most likely not help, it will increase the full gc times instead. What it might do is delay the onset of the starvation.

**If there is no change in usage, then the only cause is something in ignite.** 

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: thanks for the comment, it is a recurring incident unfortunately as i mentioned before when the cluster restarted the pattern occurs after 24-36 hours. configuration and client behavior have not changed.